# JavaScript Array.reduce divide

Tags: javascript

I have code in my application that multiplies numbers together using array.reduce.
It looks like this:

```
// Private function to multiply field values together
function _multipleFields(product, fields) {

    // Calculate our total        
    var total = fields.reduce(function (total, field) {

        // Get our number from our field
        var fieldValue = helper.getPropertyValue(product, field.trim()),
            number = _extractNumber(fieldValue);

        return total * number;
    }, 1);

    // Return our total
    return total;
};
```

I would like to use similar logic to divide numbers. 
I thought I would be able to just change the operator, but **total** in the first iteration is equal to **1**. For multiplication that is fine, but for division it isn't.

Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: what do you mean by divide? What's your use case? Can you give an example?

Comment: The two operations are fundamentally very different though. One is commutative, the other is not: `a * b == b * a`, but `a  / b != b / a`

Comment: Given an array `[a, b, c]` do you want `((a / b) / c)`?    What if there's just one element in the array?

Answer (score 3):

If your intent is to produce e.g. `((a / b) / c)` given the input array `[a, b, c]` then you should *omit* the "initial value" field because there is no "identity" value for the division operator in the way that "0" is the identity to addition and "1" is the identity for multiplication.

```
function divideArray(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(total, number) {
        return total / number;
    });
}
```

This will reduce (pun not really intended) to just returning the original value if only a single value is supplied since by definition the `reduce` function does not call its callback if only a single value is supplied.

With appropriate separation of concerns and simplification of functions to their smallest testable units, your entire code could reduce to:

```
function _getFieldNumber(product, field) {
    return _extractNumber(helper.getPropertyValue(product, field.trim()));
}

function _getFieldNumbers(product, fields) {
    return fields.map(_getFieldNumber.bind(this, product));
}

function _multipleFields(product, fields) {
    return _getFieldNumbers(product, fields).reduce(multiply, 1);
}

function _divideFields(product, fields) {
    return _getFieldNumbers(product, fields).reduce(divide);
}

function multiply(a, b) { return a * b; }
function divide(a, b)   { return a / b; }
```

Comment: Though this is the idea way, he is fetching number using a function. So he will have to pass initial value

Comment: @Rajesh please explain more - what you've said makes no sense.  The source of the values makes no difference.

Comment: Apologies but OP is doing `number = _extractNumber(fieldValue);` to get numeric value. So doing `arr.reduce((p,c) => p/c)` will not work as even value of initialValue should be parsed using same value

Comment: @Rajesh the code above is an example of _clean_ separation of responsibilities where the mathematical operation of repeated divisions is separated from the extraction of the values from their source data.    It is not intended to exactly plug into the OP's code.  Also as explained, there _is no initial value_.

Comment: @Rajesh ideally the OP should have an `_extractFields` function that does _nothing_ but extract the values into an array, and then the implementation of `_multipleFields` and `_divideFields` would then call that first, followed by the appropriate function to perform the desired mathematical operation.  Admittedly it wouldn't be _quite_ as efficient as doing it all within one `.reduce` loop, but it would be a _lot_ cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: You are correct. Even I tried similar approach, just I made call in every iteration to get value.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using similar functions for multiplication and division, you should try to make them generic.

One way is to get first field and extract number from it and use this as initialValue for `.reduce`. This way you can keep structure same.

```js
function _operateFields(product, fields, operand) {
  var initial = getNumericValue(product, fields[0])
  var total = fields.slice(1).reduce(function(total, field) {
    var num = getNumericValue(product, field);
    return (operand === "/") ? total / num: total * num
  }, initial);
  return total;
};

function getNumericValue(product, field) {
  return _extractNumber(helper.getPropertyValue(product, field.trim()));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. I'm using `slice` and not `splice`

Comment: Also, yes your code looks way better. This is just an alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by doing this:

```
// Private function to divide field values together
function _divideFields(product, fields) {

    // Calculate our total        
    var total = fields.reduce(function (total, field) {

        // Get our number from our field
        var fieldValue = helper.getPropertyValue(product, field.trim()),
            number = _extractNumber(fieldValue);

        return total ? total / number : number;
    }, 0);

    // Return our total
    return total;
};
```

Comment: this would incorrectly (in mathematical terms at least) reset the sequence of divisions if any number in the array is zero.   If your test for non-zero total is a work around for your use of zero as the initial value, then the correct approach is _not to supply an initial value_.